# asp:TableRow set visible property not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a .NET 3.5 web application which shows/hides table rows contained in ascx files via an interface implementation (the controls containing the table implement the interface).

So, given this markup in the .ascx:

```
<asp:Table id="MyTable" runat="server">
<asp:TableRow ID="Foo" runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell ID="FooCell"
            runat="server"  ColumnSpan="3">
            //Cell contents omitted
        </asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell .... ellided
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

The interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    Table GetPageDataTable();
}
```

The implementation in the ascx's code behind:

```
#region IMyInterface Members

    public Table GetPageDataTable()
    {
        return MyTable;
    }

    #endregion
```

When I use a method like the one below from the containing page, as I loop through the table rows, the contains statement returns true however, the row's Visible property = false.

```
private void SetVisibleRows(IMyInterface control)
    {
        // the list stored in session contains 'Foo'
        List<string> choices = (List<string>)Session["selectionsList"]; 

        Table tbl = control.GetPageDataTable();

        foreach (TableRow r in tbl.Rows)
        {
            //r.ID == 'Foo'
            r.Visible = choices.Contains(r.ID, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }             
  }
```

I've also tried this directly in the control's codebehind, and even setting Foo.Visible = true; still shows visible = false in the debug window.

Any help with this would be appreciated as it's driving me batty. I have another control which implements the interface and it's working fine for that one.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your ascx or any other parent-container-control of Foo is not invisible?

Comment: It's contained within a Wizard control. But, I'm not hiding anything above it. A similar control which implements the interface works on another ActiveStepIndex.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, and thought I'd share the answer.

The call to SetVisibleRows needs to occur on the Page's OnLoadComplete Event. Trying to set row visibility before the control loads won't work.

Thanks Tim, for your response.